# Looking for a HTML reporter to use with Detox and Jest

Tags: automated-testing, regression-testing, reactjs

I desperately looking for a HTML reporter to use with detox with Jest - I need it for both smoke and regression testing.  I am testing a react-native app on iOS

I've tried `https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-html-reporter` with no success.   What's happening is that I can run the tests but I cannot produce a report of tests that have passed or failed.  It's super frustrating.

If someone can suggest something that can work with detox and jest that would be amazing.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We don't use Detox, only Jest for our React Native app. We have integrated [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru) in our Jenkins build, and are fairly happy with it.

Whether this helps your situation I can't say, as I am not fully clear what exact problem you are having.... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Allure report with Detox.  - see [this link](https://hughmccamphill.com/blog/allure-report-detox-jest-circus/) for more details.

1. It gives good insights into the test execution metrics with readily
   available and configurable metrics
2. With VS Code, Live server extension, you can launch an allure report
   every time you run with one click - which is super easy
3. Also You can visualise historical trends of test execution metrics
   over a period of time with Allure history
4. You can push the test execution results to AWS-S3 so that you can
   have a static website exposed to all the stake holders with one URL
   pointing to AWS-S3.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a good HTML reporter that works with detox (with Jest), protractor, mocha etc

[click this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coveralls)